# How do I change numeric values in a subset of columns in a R dataframe to other numeric values?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with currently 4 rows /subjects (more to come as this is ongoing research) and 259 variables /columns. 240 variables of this dataset are ratings of fit ("How well does the following adjective match the dimension X?" and 19 variables are sociodemographic.

For these 240 rating-variables, my subjects could give a rating ranging from 1 ("fits very badly") to 7 ("fits very well"). Consequently, I have a 240 variables numbered from 1 to 7. I would like to change these numeric values as follows (the procedure being the same for all of the 240 columns)

1 should change to 0, 2 should change to 1/6, 3 should change to 2/6, 4 should change to 3/6, 5 should change to 4/6, 6 should change to 5/6 and 7 should change to 1. So no matter where in the 240 columns, a 1 should change to 0 and so on.

I have tried the following approaches:

[Recode numeric values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011836/recode-numeric-values-in-r)

In this post, it says that

```
x <- 1:10

# With recode function using backquotes as arguments
dplyr::recode(x, `2` = 20L, `4` = 40L)
# [1]  1 20  3 40  5  6  7  8  9 10

# With case_when function
dplyr::case_when(
  x %in% 2 ~ 20,
  x %in% 4 ~ 40,
  TRUE ~ as.numeric(x)
)
#  [1]  1 20  3 40  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Consequently, I tried this:

```
df = ds %>% select(AD01_01:AD01_20,AD02_01:AD02_20,AD03_01:AD03_20,AD04_01:AD04_20,AD05_01:AD05_20,AD06_01:AD06_20,                      AD09_01:AD09_20,AD10_01:AD10_20,AD11_01:AD11_20,AD12_01:AD12_20,AD13_01:AD13_20,AD14_01:AD14_20)
                   %>% recode(.,`1`=0,`2`=-1/6,`3`=-2/6, `4`=3/6,`5`=4/6, `6`=5/6, `7`=1))
```

with AD01_01 etc. being the column names for the adjectives my subjects should rate. I also tried it without the `.,` after `recode(,` to no avail.

This code is flawed because it omits the 19 rows of sociodemographic data I want to keep in my dataset. Moreover, I get the error  `unexpected SPECIAL in "%>%"`.

I thought R might accept my selected columns with the pipe operator as the "x" in `recode`. Apparently, this is not the case. I also tried to read up on the R documentation of `recode` but it made things much more confusing for me, as there were a lot of technical terms I don't understand.

As there is another option mentioned in the post, I also tried this:

```
df = df %>% select(AD01_01:AD01_20,AD02_01:AD02_20,AD03_01:AD03_20,AD04_01:AD04_20,AD05_01:AD05_20,AD06_01:AD06_20,                     AD09_01:AD09_20,AD10_01:AD10_20,AD11_01:AD11_20,AD12_01:AD12_20,AD13_01:AD13_20,AD14_01:AD14_20) %>% case_when (.,%in% 1~0,%in% 2~1/6,%in%3~2/6,%in%4~3/6,%in%5~4/6,%in%6~5/6,%in%7~1)
```

I thought I could give the output of the select function to the case_when function. Apparently, this is also not the case.

When I execute this command, I get

```
Error: unexpected SPECIAL in:
"df = df %>% select(AD01_01:AD01_20,AD02_01:AD02_20,AD03_01:AD03_20,AD04_01:AD04_20,AD05_01:AD05_20,AD06_01:AD06_20,                      AD09_01:AD09_20,AD10_01:AD10_20,AD11_01:AD11_20,AD12_01:AD12_20,AD13_01:AD13_20,AD14_01:AD14_20) %>% case_when (%in%"
```

Reading up on other possibilities, I found this

https://rstudio-education.github.io/hopr/modify.html

exemplary dataset:

`head(dplyr::storms)`

```
## # A tibble: 6 x 13
##   name   year month   day  hour   lat  long status category  wind pressure
##   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <ord>    <int>    <int>
## 1 Amy    1975     6    27     0  27.5 -79   tropi… -1          25     1013
## 2 Amy    1975     6    27     6  28.5 -79   tropi… -1          25     1013
## 3 Amy    1975     6    27    12  29.5 -79   tropi… -1          25     1013
## 4 Amy    1975     6    27    18  30.5 -79   tropi… -1          25     1013
## 5 Amy    1975     6    28     0  31.5 -78.8 tropi… -1          25     1012
## 6 Amy    1975     6    28     6  32.4 -78.7 tropi… -1          25     1012
## # ... with 2 more variables: ts_diameter <dbl>, hu_diameter <dbl>

# We decide that we want to recode all NAs to 9999.

storm <- storms

storm$ts_diameter[is.na(storm$ts_diameter)] <- 9999
summary(storm$ts_diameter)

ds$AD01_01:AD01_20[1(ds$AD01_01:AD01_20)] <- 0, ds$AD01_01:AD01_20[2(ds$AD01_01:AD01_20)] <- 1/6, ds$AD01_01:AD01_20[3(ds$AD01_01:AD01_20)] <- 2/6, 
ds$AD01_01:AD01_20[4(ds$AD01_01:AD01_20)] <- 3/6, ds$AD01_01:AD01_20[5(ds$AD01_01:AD01_20)] <- 4/6, ds$AD01_01:AD01_20[6(ds$AD01_01:AD01_20)] <- 5/6, 
ds$AD01_01:AD01_20[7(ds$AD01_01:AD01_20)] <- 1
```

My idea in this case was to use `assign` for multiple columns at a time (this effort just concerns 20 of my 240 columns and it also didn't work. I got the error
`could not find function ":<-"` which is weird because I thought this was a basic command. The only noteworthy thing that might explain is that I executed `library(readr)` and `library(tidyverse)` beforehand.

Disclaimer: I am an R newbie and have spent 2 hours to try to solve this issue. I would also like to know where I went wrong and why my code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `mutate(across())`?  For example, if all your "adjective rating" columns start with "AD", you can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
ds %>% mutate(across(starts_with("AD"), ~(.x-1)/6))
```

#### Explanation of where you went wrong with your code:

First, your `select(...) %>% recode(...)` was close. However, when you use `select`, you are reducing `ds` to only the selected columns, thus recoding those values and assigning to `df` will result in `df` not having the demographic variables.

Second, if you want to use `recode` you can, but you can't feed it an entire data frame/tibble, like you are doing when you pipe (`%>%`) the selected columns to it. Instead, you can use `recode()` iteratively in `.fns`, on each of the columns in the `.cols` param of `across()`, like this:

```
ds %>%
  mutate(across(
    .cols = starts_with("AD"),
    .fns = ~recode(.x,`1`=0,`2`=-1/6,`3`=-2/6, `4`=3/6,`5`=4/6, `6`=5/6, `7`=1))
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) I tried both versions you suggested. The first version works fine, if I run the second version I get

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `AD01_01`.
Caused by error in `recode()`:
! `.default` must have class `numeric`, not class `avector/numeric`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I think the first solution you provided is very elegant, as it is just 1 short line of code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: okay, the latter is being caused by the class of your variables that you are passing to `recode()`. I don't have access to your data.. When I create the mock variables `AD01_01` etc that are numeric, I don't see the error that you see.. Regardless, I think the first approach is probably better than recode, since the recoding can be simply formulated as `(value-1)/6`